# Hold original XML content into unmarshalled object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a set of objects ready to be used with JAXB.
Every class implements the `com.sun.xml.bind.Locatable` interface.

Question:
During JAXB unmarhalling process, is it possibile to store into the unmarshalled object the source XML text associated to object?

Comment: I think what you need is [Binder](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html)

Comment: TY for you comment. I checked Binder javadoc, but Binder requests to read into DOM and I want to avoid this (I don't need update XML capability). My need is less complicated: just store original XML without ability to update original document. Any other advice?